# Is it possible to make a border-radius behave like in figma

Tags: css, figma

Is it possible to make css behave like in figma, its hard for me to describe but basically the border radius would go past the middle point.

Css doesn't behave like that when i tell him `border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 50px;` it stops at the middle and squares the top left, is there a way to force css to behave like the image

[image: figma behaviour]

the code i guess

html:

```
<div class="decoracaoInfo1" id="decoracaoInfo1"> </div>
```

css:

```
.decoracaoInfo1{
    width: 397px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(53, 92, 175, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid rgba(53, 92, 175, 0.0); 
    border-radius: 50px;/*0px 100px 100px 100px;*/
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    z-index:5;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: theres not much code... @dalelandry there, i don't think theres too much to do with it, 
the code isnt relevant

Comment: I understand, however without code to go with your question you will get negative feed back from the community and your question may get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of [border-radius definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) is the key to get the desired shape. The shorthand is applied top-left to bottom-left, clockwise.

```css
.shape {
    width: 397px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(53, 92, 175, 0.6);
    border-radius: 0 12.5px 12.5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! i don't really get why it works but it does

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more obvious what happens.